# Can't access memory and segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, struct, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement two structures and they work fine till one point.

```
typedef struct punct{
int x;
int y;

} COORD;

typedef struct nod{
COORD *coord;
struct nod *urm;

} NOD;
```

I think the problem is that I am pointing to the wrong place here:

```
NOD *crt, *cap, *urm;
crt=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
cap=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
cap->urm=crt;
crt->urm=NULL;


for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

    NOD *next=(NOD*)malloc(sizeof(NOD));
    next->urm =NULL;
    COORD *coordo = (COORD*)malloc(sizeof(COORD));
    coordo->x=coordonate[i].x; //these are just some elements from an array, they work fine
    coordo->y=coordonate[i].y;
    next->coord=coordo; //here I think is what is causing the problem
    crt->urm=next;

    crt=next;
}
```

Although I think that there is the place where I am missing something, the error appears later when I try to print the coordinates:

```
 crt=cap->urm;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%d %d\n",crt->coord->x,crt->coord->y); //this is where the "Can't acces memory at adress ..."    
error and the segmentation fault appears from. I've tested with the debuger.
    urm=crt->urm;
    crt=urm;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Don't break up the code. Post it all in one complete, minimal block.

Comment: You never initialized `coord` for the first 2 nodes. But your loop tries to dereference that.

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names than `cap`, `crt`, and `urm`. I have no idea what they do and it makes it a lot harder to read.

Comment: And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Yep, I've added  "crt->coord= (COORD*)malloc(sizeof(COORD));" and it works ok now. Thanks guys!